# How can the email sender reply address say "do not reply"?

Tags: php, email, pear, yahoo

Today I registered myself on [Pinterest.com](http://www.pinterest.com) with my Yahoo account. After registration I got an email for email validation, at the bottom of the email this message was showed by Yahoo:

> Sender reply address says do not reply

and I could also hide this message, I mean it was not in the body of email.

Here is screenshot of my email: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spdw5.jpg

My question is:

How can I use this option when I use 'PHP PEAR' or default mail() function?

Comment: Was the sender's email address `no-reply@<domain>` or something similar by any chance? If that's the case you can 'use' this option by using a similar email address.

Comment: I did not ever notice this "feature" in any of my emails so I would suggest this is a feature of yahoo and not of php itself. They are recognizing the senders email as (typical) noreply@yourdomain.com and show this message.

Comment: I checked my email, the sender's email address is 'Pinterest <pinbot@pinterest.com>'!

Comment: "Sender reply address says do not reply" - sounds like yahoo parses the reply-to header. Can you post all headers of this email?

Comment: Is there a way to see the raw content of the email you received? With headers and all.

Comment: The header of email is something like what Gryphius mentioned, but I've not tested yet. Apart of header: MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Subject: Thanks for Joining the Pinterest Waiting List
From: Pinterest <pinbot@pinterest.com>
Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2012 14:22:07 -0000
Message-ID: <20120202142207.7467.97160@pyres017.ec2.pin220.com>
Reply-To: no-reply@pinterest.com
X-Sendgrid-EID: pdaC91Sn/uNZIU54cZiD...
Content-Length: 1340

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yahoo parses the reply-to header. set a header like this:

```
Reply-To: noreply@example.com
```

replace example.com with your sender domain.

it should work with either mail() (see example by Zac) or Pear

```
[....]
$headers["Reply-To"]="noreply@example.com";
$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```

`no-reply` instead of `noreply` works as well. Your email from pinterest.com for example has a header `Reply-To: no-reply@pinterest.com`

Answer (score 1):

Using standard `mail()` simple example as follows:

```
$headers = array(
        'From: No reply',
        'Content-Type: text/html'
        );

        $subject = "This is a subject";
        $message = 'Some email message goes in here';

        $to = 'someone@example.com';

        mail($to,$subject,$message,implode("\r\n",$headers));
```

Comment: Thank your for you answer, but this solution doesn't effect like what I said. When you try by this way Yahoo act as normal email. I will attache a print screen then you can see what I mean.